# Geo Blocking in Wordpress - how can it be implemented?

Tags: geo-data

I've tried to search for a geo-blocking plugin for wordpress - didn't find anything.

So thought to ask here if anyone knows of a geo-blocking solution for wordpress sites?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves, Bad Behavior allows to configure a few aspects of geo-blocking. There might be a few wp.org plugins tagged as security that allow to implement geo-blocking too.

That said, I don't think it's the right approach. The best is to hop over to askapache.com. There's tons of security-related, htaccess-based stuff over there. Geo-blocking is among them.

Comment: Or if you want to stay in the Stack Exchange network, maybe [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) offers good advice.